# Getting Typescript or Eslint error when referencing the assigned variable before initialization with useMemo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm using latest Typescript and Typescript eslint rules and currently this code doesn't cause an error before runtime:

```
  const a: string = useMemo(() => {
    return a;
  }, []);
```

Is there a way to make it work?

When using it like this without useMemo, there will be a Typescript error `Block-scoped variable 'a' used before its declaration.ts(2448)`.

```
  const a: string = (() => {
    return a;
  })();
```

Comment: can you provide details regarding what you want your code to do??

Answer (score 0):

That's a power of js's [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#closure).

A function inside another function makes its lexical environment that arrow access to variables outside of the wrapper function scope. The first one(useMemo) is in this case.

On the other hand, second one without useMemo is just arrow function execution and it only maintains its function block scope where variable a is not declared.

Comment: Do you think that's too much for ESLint to catch such errors?

Comment: @k4rli Yes. That actually causes a runtime error in JS. You can see the error in your browser console with ` const a = (() => {return a;})();` statement.